# Is there a way of accessing records from a non persisted association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

I have the following classes:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  has_many :post_tags                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags
end

class PostTag < ApplicationRecord                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  belongs_to :post                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  has_many :post_tags                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  has_many :posts, through: :post_tags
end
```

and the following test (rspec)

```rb
RSpec.describe Post, :model do
  let(:post) { Post.new }
  let(:post_tag) { PostTag.new tag: tag }
  let(:tag) { Tag.new }

  before do
    PostTag.destroy_all
  end

  # passes
  it 'sets tags when setting tags association' do
    post.tags << tag
    expect(post.tags).not_to be_empty
  end

  # fails
  it 'sets tags when setting post_tags association' do
    post.post_tags << post_tag
    expect(post.tags).not_to be_empty
  end
end
```

Is there a way to set the `PostTag` association (`has_many`) and be able to get a collection proxy of `Post` instances when calling `posts` (`has_many :thorugh`) association **without saving the record**?

more context:

I want to implement a duplicate method and I need to duplicate the associations too, the join model has extra information like `post_tag.name` that I don't want to lose on duplication

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  has_many :post_tags                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags

  def duplicate
    new_instance = dup
    new_instance.post_tags = post_tags.map(&:dup)
    new_instance
  end
end
```

I tried to do it in the way of the test that passes (setting the `tags` via the `has_many :through`) association, but that means I will lose data that is stored in the `PostTags` instances. Is there a way to set the `post_tags` and get the `tags` without persisting?

Comment: No not really. I don't get why you would need a name on the join table though and it smells like data duplication.

Comment: this is just an example, in the join table there is information that is relevant to the join, like for example, patients and doctors, a patien visits many doctors though an appointment, the appointment is the join table that makes the relation between the patient and the doctor and you need the information from the apointment like dates and hours, just an example

Comment: The core problem here is really that a join table is a combination of foreign keys from table A and table B. A PostTag can't actually belong to multiple Posts - you would have to have an additional table for that to be possible which creates a M2M association. If you wanted to "duplicate" the tags belonging to a Post so that another post has the same tags you would copy the tag_id (and any other attributes) and create new instances of the join model but with a different post_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can confidently say the answer is 'no'.

```rb
it 'sets tags when setting post_tags association' do
  post.post_tags << post_tag # post_tag has no ID yet, it's not saved.
  expect(post.tags).not_to be_empty
end
```

`post.tags` relies on `has_many :tags, through: :post_tags`

So the SQL of `post.tags` will be something like:

```rb
SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "post_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "post_tags"."post_id" WHERE "post_tags"."post_id" = 22
```

This requires `post_tags` and `tags` to be records in the database that can be retrieved.

I bet this test would pass if you saved the records first:

```rb
RSpec.describe Post, :model do
  let(:post) { Post.new }
  let(:post_tag) { PostTag.new tag: tag }
  let(:tag) { Tag.new }

  it 'sets tags when setting post_tags association' do
    post_tag.save
    tag.save

    post.post_tags << post_tag.reload
    expect(post.tags).not_to be_empty
  end
end
```

But this isn't the behavior you want, I'm guessing.

Is there an issue with multiple `post`s having the same `post_tag`s?

```rb
def duplicate
  new_instance = dup
  new_instance.post_tags = post_tags # don't make dupes .map(&:dup)
  new_instance
end
```